# How to "do something" after an EJB3 transaction commit?

Tags: transactions, ejb, ejb-3.1, post-commit

Is there something in EJB3 that allows me to execute some code just after the transaction commit (I want to send XMPP messages to notify external devices for updates) ?

I know I can do something like that using JTA API and enlisting my own writed XA resource but I have the feeling that's it's not the right tool.

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a stateful session bean that implements javax.ejb.SessionSynchronization, and call a method from within the transaction.  The afterCompletion method will be called with the outcome of the transaction.

Update: if you're using EJB 3.1, you can annotate a method of the SFSB with @AfterCompletion rather than implementing the interface.

Comment: I've just seen you answer. Thx, it's exactly what I'm lokking for.